# Multiple truststores in play framework - jvm

Tags: java, ssl, https, playframework, jvm

Currently I try to make a play application be able to communicate SSL encrypted with the database. 
I created self-signed certificate and CA for mysql. There is no problem with that normally, I can make the application communicate with the db server encrypted, when I add this CA to the JAVA_OPTS

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/app/path/conf/truststore
```

Everything goes well until my application not tries to communicate with other sites via SSL:

```
 java.net.ConnectException: General SSLEngine problem to https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?<meh>
    [...]
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    [...]
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    [...]
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    [...]
```

The error is pretty obvious: twitter's ssl cert cannot be checked, because my truststore doesn't contains the CA which signed twitters certificate. IIRC I cannot add more than one "javax.net.ssl.trustStore" parameter for JVM, so I have to inject my CA's into the play framework. For luck, play framework supports ssl, and regarding the documentation I can add multiple truststores: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/WsSSL
I created a config file for ssl:

```
play.ws.ssl {
  trustManager = {
      stores = [
        { path: /path/to/truststore, type: "JKS", password = "<whatever is it" }
        { path: ${java.home}/lib/security/cacerts } # Default trust store
      ]
  }
```

But when I start the server, I got the following error message:

```
Oops, cannot start the server.
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
```

And now, I am stuck. I can inject my truststore for JVM, but when I do this, the app cannot communicate with other SSL enabled hosts - there's no cert, but when I try to add my truststore for play framework it doesn't accept it, because nobody signed my cert. 
Is there a way to solve this somehow? I suspect if I take the system wide cacert file (which is used by java) and my truststore, and then I merge them with keytool, it will solve this, but this is not the best way - it would be more sane if I could pack my self signed certs next to the application.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for some reason my own trust store wouldn't be recognized so I ended up adding my certificate to the default keystore (${java.home}/lib/security/cacerts). You can use this command to do this (BTW cacerts default password is changeit):

`keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore alice.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore "c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_71\lib\security\cacerts"  -deststoretype JKS`

Then you need to have the trustManager and the key manager defined. The trustManager points to the trust store and the keyManager to your certificate.

```
play.ws.ssl {
  trustManager = {
    stores = [
      {
        path: ${java.home}/lib/security/cacerts 
      }
    ]
  }
  keyManager = {
    stores = [
      {
        type: "PKCS12",
        path: "/Users/work/Documents/path/to/certificate/certificate.p12",
        password: "pass"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That error means Play can't find the stores. Is the path correct?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message: `java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty` caused by empty store. According to [Key store docs](https://lightbend.github.io/ssl-config/KeyStores.html) there could be `password` field in the configuration but it was ignored therefore certificates were not read from the store. I had to use PEM format or you can include certificates in config see [Configure store](https://lightbend.github.io/ssl-config/KeyStores.html#configuring-a-store). The password field is added/put back in [commit #e867e729](https://github.com/lightbend/ssl-config/commit/e867e729e9dd5fee15c54f5ca233ffb913b1e41a#diff-5ff8d274a012378fc19a629ab3dba08a). I'm on Play 2.6 so I couldn't test it.